# Disabling Collapse event of a root node in Treeview in .NET

Tags: c#

I am developing a application in which i need to prevent collapsable behaviour of a root node in tree view.
I tried using Before Select event.
Is there any alternative for it?

Answer (score 3):

You need `BeforeCollapse` event:

```
private void OnBeforeCollapse(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if(!CanCollapse(e.Node)) e.Cancel = true;
}
```

It assumes you have a `CanCollapse` function, which determines if node can be collapsed.